# Set anchor for bitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to set the anchor point to the middle of the bitmap. By default it is always the top-left corner of the bitmap.

If I try:

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, paint);
```

It always starts drawing the bitmap from the top left. However it can be fixed by subtracting half of the width/height to the x/y point.

```
int widthOffset = bitmap.getWidth()/2;
int heightOffset = bitmap.getHeight()/2;
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x-widthOffset, y-heightOffset, paint);
```

Is there any other solution which sets the anchor by default to the center of the bitmap?

Comment: I suppose that there is no way to set default anchor.

Comment: I thought that maybe this could do the trick for the x and y value.

createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, x, y, width, height)

but didn't get it working though.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html